# Regex to match one or three underscores like "(1_2)_(3_4)" or "(12)_(34)"

Tags: php, regex

Currently the regexp that is used is:

```
/(^|[\s(])parent_(\w+)_(\w+)\.name/
```

Now that collides if the word to match has an underscore in it.
Is there an easy way to handle this?

`parent_accounts_accounts.name` works

Result: `accounts accounts`

`parent_my_module_my_module.name` does not work

Result: `my_module_my module`

Expected: `my_module my_module`

Comment: How should `parent_my_other_module.name` be treated?

Comment: Which part of it is constant and which is dynamic?

Comment: I think if one of the words contains a underscore, the other one would too.
So parent_my_other_module.name wont happen hopefully.

Comment: "parent_" the middle "_" and ".name" is constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
/\bparent_([a-z]+_?[a-z]+)_([a-z]+_?[a-z]+).name/ig
```

or

```
/\bparent_((([a-z]+_[a-z]+)_([a-z]+_[a-z]+))|(([a-z]+)_([a-z]+)))\.name/ig
```

The second one checks that if your first part has an `_` the second part must have it too.

Comment: The first one before the edit was better as it kept the result in the same position in result. So now i use:

/(^|[\s(])parent_([a-zA-Z]+_?[a-zA-Z]+)_([a-zA-Z]+_?[a-zA-Z]+)\.name/

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem in your approach: you need to define, how many underscores can a name contain. For instance, in your example `parent_my_module_my_module.name` regexp matcher does not know whether the output should be `my module_my_module`, `my_module my_module` or `my_module_my module`. This happens when you allow a name to contain a limiter (`_` in your case).

The most common approach are so called [escape characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character). Such a character is usually a backslash `\`. When you write a string e.g. `$str = "Hello world";` and you want to you `"` in it, you take an advantage of the backslash and you write `$str = "Hello \"world\"";`.

I think the best solution is to disallow underscores in names and define them explicitly as limiters, so that you will only need a little modification to your regexp:

```
/\bparent_([^_]+)_([^_]+)\.name/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nT3lP9/1)

Comment: The Problem is that the software i want to do a little bugfix ( sugarcrm ), gives me the underscore for my custom modules, and does not for the stock modules.
So if there is no possible regex, maybe i use an if depending of the contained underscores.

Comment: @Gunni Then I'd consider using a different limiter. Could you use `-` instead of `_`? Then you'd have `/\bparent-([^-]+)-([^-]+)\.name/` and you could use as many underscores in names as you wish:)

Comment: I can not easyly exchange the delimiter, but shA.t answer above helped me to fix that.